# Determine the shape of multiple selected cells within a data grid

Tags: .net, datagrid, matrix, infragistics, point

I'm using the Infragistics UltraWinGrid to present some data. I need some Excel copy/paste functionality. That's the easy bit.

1. What I want to do is determine the *shape* of the selection, and ensure it's a rectangle of adjacent cells. If it's not, an error is to be shown (as pasting said data will just lead to errors).
2. I then need to detect all the boundary edge cells so I can put a "you've copied this" border around the cells, ala Excel.

I'm hoping to achieve this by comparing a list of Point structures or something along those lines.

To illustrate the problem better, here are some pictures:

[image: Working image]

*1. This is fine, see the edge cells (duh)*

[image: Fail image]]

*2. This won't work, I've tried to copy too much, show an error*

[image: Another fail image]

*3. The user hasn't learnt by now that this just won't work. You can even see where I've copied the "wrong" cell out of sheer lazyness.*

I've got a Dictionary of Points and Cells, ready to work with. Any ideas? C#/VB is fine.

**UPDATE:**
This might help?

Taking the second diagram:

```
0,0 1,0 2,0
0,1 1,1 2,1
0,2 1,2 2,2
0,3 1,3 2,3
    1,4     <<< wrong
```

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Also, I think part of the problem is that I don't know what the rectangle boundaries are in the first place...

Comment: To make sure I understand: so you want to check this shape before pasting a selection from Excel into the grid? And is a range of cells with a hole in it allowed?

Comment: @GertArnold Kinda yes, but rather than Excel it'll be my own DataGrid control. Today I wrote a little algorithm to enumerate the selected cells and produce a list of points, then translate them so they're zero based (e.g. {1,2}{1,3} becomes {0,1}{0,2} etc), it's a start. In fact from here I can write the actual copy/paste functionality. I used LINQ GroupBy() to group on X and Y coords thus producing the count of Rows and Columns (`cells.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Row).Count()`). Finally I wrote a bit that extends the pasted region based upon what's been copied, so progress is being made!

Comment: Ok. There are algorithms out there for finding minimum or maximum rectangle in a point cloud. With 'large' selections you may need optimizations that such algorithms offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've had a good think about this and GertArnold has pointed me in the right direction, simply by saying *"range of cells with a hole in it allowed?"*

This is what happens when you spend 6 months not coding or problem solving, due to massive paperwork and auditing requirements, you forget how to even begin a simple algorithm.

It's so easy it hurts. Firstly I get the cells from the datasheet and reformat them so they're based at zero (as opposed to their actual position on the grid). I do this by simply negating the value of the cell at `{0,0}` and applying this to all the cells.

To calculate the gaps, do this:

```
Private Function HasGapsInCells(points As List(Of CellPoint)) As Boolean

    Dim colCount As Integer = points.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Column).Count()
    Dim rowCount As Integer = points.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Row).Count()

    For row As Integer = 0 To rowCount - 1
        Dim rowL As Integer = row
        For col As Integer = 0 To colCount - 1
            Dim colL As Integer = col
            If Not points.Exists(Function(x) x.Row = rowL And x.Column = colL) Then
                Return True '-- There are gaps'
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

So easy.

Comment: Ouch! Simple indeed. Now push on for a routine that does the paperwork for you!